# Show Straight Vertical Line based on Document Property drop-down selection

Tags: spotfire

The issue i am facing is easy to understand but harder to solution (at least for me). I have not found much googling this.

Probem: I would like to include a straight line to represent a fixed value of 28 on a line chart only when document property has "x" selected, otherwise, if document property "y" is selected, the line should move from 28 to 10, if document property has value "z" selected, then straight line should disappear (NULL).

By the way, this is the same document property (dropdown selection that is called ${firstStartORAssignedTime}.

Thank you in advance and apologies for having no code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line charts Properties > Line & Curves > add a Horizonal Line as a custom expression and use the following :

```
case  when "${firstStartORAssignedTime}"='x' then 28
when "${firstStartORAssignedTime}"='y' then 10
else null end
```

> ${DocumentPropertyName}

Will return the TEXT value off the document property so wrapping it in " " for the expression is needed.

> DocumentProperty("DocumentPropertyName")

Will Return the Value of the document property (ie: a string , integer ect )

So you can also use :

```
case  when DocumentProperty("firstStartORAssignedTime")='x' then 28 
when DocumentProperty("firstStartORAssignedTime")='y' then 10
else null end
```